# Problem with duration value of HTML5 audio element in iOs

Tags: html, audio, mobile-safari

I'm developing a web app for iOs device, but I have a problem with the html5 audio tag...
I designed a custom audio player, and I control the song with javascript functions.
With safari desktop the app works well, but on safari mobile it doesn't recognize the duration of the audio; the value of the duration property is NaN.
I have to play, stop and replay the audio for retrieve the correct value.
Probably the cause is that the media preload is disabled on safari mobile...
Is there a way to read the correct value at the first shot?

Comment: Theree was some js event telling when audio metadata is available. Did you try it?

Comment: thanks... I solved the problem adding a listener to the "onloadedmetadata" event; when the meta are loaded, I call a set-up function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The medata is available after this event has fired:

```
 loadedmetadata
```

More info

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introducing_the_Audio_API_Extension

Comment: For me it was the `loadedmetadata` event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata

Comment: Thanks. Removed unnecessary on.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I ended up sending the duration with the mp3.

Answer (score 11):

This is a bug in iOS... even inside the function that gets called on the `onloadedmetadata` event, you MAY STILL get `NaN`.

In my case, this happens at random when the user selects a new mp3 and the code dynamically sets the `src` property. The audio plays fine, yet SOMETIMES, the duration returns `NaN`, screwing up any progress indicator that depends on that value.