# HTML5 audio duration issue

Tags: ipad, html, html5-video, html5-audio, jplayer

I am using [jplayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) to play audio and video files in Ipad, But the issue is if i change video or audio url, sometimes i get duration NaN.

Please help me.

Comment: Please, add some piece of code.

Comment: code does not matter....its working in all browsers except Ipad

Answer (score 2):

The medata is available after `onloadedmetadata` event has fired.

(c) https://stackoverflow.com/a/7275714/492641

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Check your server has Range requests enabled.

From [this page](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-server-response) on the Jplayer site:

> Your server must enable Range requests. This is easy to check for by
>   seeing if your server's response includes the Accept-Ranges in its
>   header. Most HTML5 browsers enable seeking to new file positions
>   during a download, so the server must allow the new Range to be
>   requested.
>
> Failure to accept byte Range requests will cause problems on some
>   HTML5 browsers. Often the duration cannot be read from the file as
>   some formats require that the start and end of the file is read to
>   know its duration. Chrome tends to be the browser that has most
>   problems if the Range request is not enabled on the server, but all
>   browsers will have some issue even if it is only that you have to wait
>   for all the media to load before jumping close to the end.