# jQuery jPlayer not showing duration on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, jplayer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML5 audio duration issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101446/html5-audio-duration-issue)

I am using jPlayer on my website and it is all working fine. Even on Safari on Mac.

But when it comes to load the website from the Safari in iPad, the duration show NaN (not a number).

This is how I start the player:

```
$('#someId').jPlayer({
    supplied: 'mp3'
    ,swfPath: '/libjs_geral/jPlayer.2.1.0/js'                   
    ,wmode: 'window'
    ,ready: function () {
        $(this)
        .jPlayer('setMedia', { mp3: mp3Url })
        .jPlayer('play');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your server has Range requests enabled.

From [this page](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-server-response) on the Jplayer site:

> Your server must enable Range requests. This is easy to check for by
>   seeing if your server's response includes the Accept-Ranges in its
>   header. Most HTML5 browsers enable seeking to new file positions
>   during a download, so the server must allow the new Range to be
>   requested.
>
> Failure to accept byte Range requests will cause problems on some
>   HTML5 browsers. Often the duration cannot be read from the file as
>   some formats require that the start and end of the file is read to
>   know its duration. Chrome tends to be the browser that has most
>   problems if the Range request is not enabled on the server, but all
>   browsers will have some issue even if it is only that you have to wait
>   for all the media to load before jumping close to the end.

Comment: If you find questions that are identical to earlier ones, please comment and flag them as duplicates instead of copying and pasting the same answer, to reduce clutter and noise.