# How can I make jPlayer show the track duration before hitting play?

Tags: jplayer

I'm using jPlayer to show an audio player for mp3 files, and the duration field shows `00:00` until I hit the play button, and then it shows the correct duration while playing.  (Note that this is a **different** symptom than in [this similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101446/html5-audio-duration-issue) question.)

How can I get jPlayer to pick up and display the duration *before* the user hits the play button (so they know how long the audio clip is before deciding to play it)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that jPlayer supports the HTML5 `preload` argument, such that adding `preload: 'auto'` to the jPlayer constructor options fixes this problem and displays the track duration.  However, this also downloads the whole audio file, which is annoying, because it can use a lot of bandwidth for an audio track that the user may never play.  And it's even worse in my case, because I've got a page with a dozen user stories, and the page downloads *all* of them.

Frustratingly, there's an option `preload: 'metadata'`, which sounds like it should do exactly what I want, namely, download the track metadata without downloading the whole file, but this doesn't seem to work.  This is apparently something that browsers *should* support, but don't yet.

For now, I'll either skip this feature, or build a server side piece to check the duration and stream it via separate AJAX call.