# mobile jquery onclick does not play audio file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-mobile, onclick

This is my script

```
function playSound(soundfile) {

document.getElementById("ui-btn-text").innerHTML=document.getElementById("ui-btn-text").innerHTML +
"<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";

}
```

And this is a part of my code

```
<a style='font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:200%;' 
id="ui-btn-text" onclick="playSound('image/button.mp3');" 
href="#" data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide"></a>
```

I have no idea why the audio file does not play!

Or is there a better solution for what i am doing?

Comment: Could you format the code please?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it written it should result in some HTML like:

```
<a style='font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:200%;' id="ui-btn-text" onclick="playSound('image/button.mp3');" href="#" data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide">
    <embed src="image/button.mp4" hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" />
</a>
```

If it's going to be hidden already, why not just leave it someplace on the page and simply trigger the audio to play when the button is clicked. Set `autostart="false"` and then use JS/JQuery to play the mp4 when the button is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<a style='font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:200%;' id="ui-btn-text" onclick="playSound('ui-btn-sound');" href="#" data-ajax="false" data-transition="slide">
</a>
<embed src="image/button.mp4" hidden="true" autostart="false" loop="false" id="ui-btn-sound" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function playSound(id) {
    var audioFile = document.getElementById(id);
    audioFile.Play();
    return false;
}
```

I personally would suggest using HTML5 `audio` tag and fall back to an embedded option if needed.

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="image/button.mp4" type="audio/mp4">
    <!-- Fail Over -->
    <embed src="image/button.mp4" hidden="true" autostart="false" loop="false" id="ui-btn-sound" />
    <a href="" onclick="playSound('ui-btn-sound')">Play</a>
</audio>
```

The `audio` tag also has lots of ways to control it's look and function via JS/JQuery. You might want to look into things like `audio.canPlayType('audio/mp4');`.
Here is an older example, someone challenged me to make a piano that did not have lag between each note and allowed other notes to be stopped when a new note was played: http://www.yrmailfrom.me/projects/html5/piano.php

Edit:
After answering this, I was inspired to create a quick JQM HTML5 player: http://www.yrmailfrom.me/projects/html5/audioplay.php

Hope that helps you.

Comment: The audio file plays when the page is loaded, but when i clicked on the link it does not, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Been testing with FireFox, Chrome, Dolphin, and Safari and its work as expected in all of them, minor issues in Chrome calculating the Duration for some reason. Can you clarify the browser and version you are using. Feel free to PM me too.

Comment: +1 for the nice player, even though the "progress bar" does not work :P

Comment: Which browser do you not see it working in @dualed It works for me. And thanks for the +1

Comment: Firefox and Chrome (both current stable). In Firefox the numeric display left of the progress bar shows a "NaN" after moving it. Also I get an error in the log that an audio file is not supported (*Specified "type" attribute of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource songs/mp3/Spirit_Of_Life.mp3 failed.*), not sure about that as I *do* hear audio playing. And an error I was not able to trace "Empty string passed to getElementById()." in `jquery.min...js`

Comment: Thanks @dualed I will look into it. FireFox does not support MP3 format... no idea why. So I set the page to run both MP3 and OGG as sources. So one fails, the other loads. Since OGG appears to be supported by almost all the browsers, I use it as my common denominator. The NaN I get sometimes... this should be set to 0 by default and then incrimented by the current duration count `currentTime` method. Have to investigate more.

Comment: So I was able to replicate your issue @dualed on the first load of the site only. The issue is that if a Duration is not defined, the NaN is the result of the `parseInt()`. When I reload the page, it works properly. Will keep investigating.

Comment: Was able to reproduce this in FF @Twisty. However not in Chrome, it does not behave differently after a reload. Maybe the Browser needs some time before it can read the duration?

Comment: I agree @dualed. I made some updates: http://www.yrmailfrom.me/projects/html5/audioplay.php

Comment: @Twisty put `if (isNaN(dur)) { dur = parseInt(audio.duration, 10); $("#songPosition").attr("max", dur); }` in `timeupdate` event handler somewhere close to the start :)

Comment: I played around a bit more @Twisty : http://jsfiddle.net/yehNR/6/ (got rid of the polling code from above and ... +seeking!) It does not seem to work with any of my mobile browsers though, not really sure why

Comment: Great seek functions, thanks @dualed I took some of the things you did and forked my own: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/56afL/ testing in a number of browsers now.

Comment: Plus I found some details for `onLoadMetaData` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246172/problem-with-duration-value-of-html5-audio-element-in-ios/7275714#7275714

Comment: I also updated my jsFiddle and it works properly, for me, in FireFox and Chrome. Safari is not playing nice. IE is straight out.